# Can't login to application using Spring Security 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've configured Spring Security in my application, but after typing correct login and password I have error "Bad credentials". I know that issue is created by encoder, but if I won't use encoder bean then I'll have runtime error that I must use encoder bean. I have no idea how don't use encoder.

My spring security configuration file below

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <sec:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        <sec:user-service>
            <sec:user name="admin" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code above try removing the encoder from the section like below:-

Before Spring Security 5:-

```
<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <!-- Commented the password encoder -->
        <!--<sec:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>-->
        <sec:user-service>
            <sec:user name="admin" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

after this try logging in using the `username` - **admin** and `password` - **123456**

**UPDATE**

After Spring Security 5:-

```
<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <sec:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        <sec:user-service>
            <sec:user name="admin" password="{bcrypt}$2a$10$s7hvVL8HeHQZ6bgRl0y0C.2TYZ1wsFd262P8/XqOJuac6LphLIusG" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

Important thing to note here is that the encrypted value of `123456` is `$2a$10$s7hvVL8HeHQZ6bgRl0y0C.2TYZ1wsFd262P8/XqOJuac6LphLIusG` using `BCryptPasswordEncoder`

You can refer the link here - https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-format

The link will guide you better for the encoding changes after spring 5 and what all things/encoding types are possible

Comment: thank you, I tried your solution, but I had `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"`

Comment: something that changed after spring 5, more reading here - https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-format

Comment: thank you, I've added {noop} to password and it works, but {bcrypt} doesn't work.

Comment: {noop} is for plain text encoding

Comment: Yes, I tried bcrypt, but anyway have "Bad credentials"

Comment: thats great, the article is awesome and precise

Comment: you added password like this for bcrypt?

`{bcrypt}$2a$10$s7hvVL8HeHQZ6bgRl0y0C.2TYZ1wsFd262P8/XqOJuac6LphLIusG` encoded value for 123456